# Whats wrong with this powershell Foreach-Object statement?

Tags: powershell

I have a function called "Get-Connections" which returns a list of some sql connections, for example:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Connections
    
Id                    : e1a2fd17-91aa-4975-b1ee-1a7df65e6d6b
DataSource            : myDataSource1
InitialCatalog        : myInitCatalog
UseIntegratedSecurity : True
DisplayName           : testConnection

Id                    : 2688f2af-1b49-405f-aa92-417a43b76dca
DataSource            : myDataSource1
InitialCatalog        : myInitCatalog
UseIntegratedSecurity : True
DisplayName           : testConnection
```

I also have a function called "Remove-connection" which removes a connection by Id:

```
Remove-Connection "2688f2af-1b49-405f-aa92-417a43b76dca"
```

Now I tryed to remove all connections using

```
Get-Connections | % { Remove-Connection $_.Id }
```

This doesnt work, Exception is:

```
Remove-Connection : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Guid' required by parameter 'Id'. Specified method is not supported.
```

What actually work is this:

```
Get-Connections | % { $_.Id } | % { Remove-Connection "$_" }
```

Whats wrong with the previous statement?

## Update 1.

Get Connection:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Connections", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
    public class GetConnectionsCommand : Cmdlet
    {
        private List<ConnectionDto> Connections { get; set; }

        public void GetConnections()
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var address = new EndpointAddress(Address);
            
            var repositoryService = new WcfConnectionRepositoryServiceProxy(binding, address);
            
            Connections = repositoryService.GetAll().ToList();
        }

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
            GetConnections();
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            base.ProcessRecord();
            WriteObject(Connections);
        }
    }
```

Remove Connection:

```
 [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Remove, "Connection", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
        public class RemoveConnectionCommand : Cmdlet
        {
            [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "Id", 
                Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, 
                 ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
                HelpMessage = "Please enter the ID of the connection to remove")]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
     
            private void RemoveConnection()
            {
                var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                var address = new EndpointAddress(Address);
    
                var repositoryService = new WcfConnectionRepositoryServiceProxy(binding, address);
                repositoryService.Delete(Id);
            }
    
            protected override void BeginProcessing()
            {
                base.BeginProcessing();
                RemoveConnection();
            }
        }
```

DTO:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ConnectionDto"]
    public class ConnectionDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string DataSource { get; set; }
        
        ...
```

Comment: what's the return type of `Get-Connections`? a list or array?

Comment: Or more specifically, what is the type of the `Id` property of the object returned by `Get-Connections`? Have you tried `Get-Connections | % { Remove-Connection $_.Id.ToString() }`?

Comment: The type of Get-Connections is a list of ConnectionDTOs. The Id property of ConnectionDTO is a GUID, and Remove-Connection also expects a GUID.
Your example doesn't work too: Remove-Connection : Cannot bind parameter 'Id'. Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Guid". Error: "Guid should contain 32 
digits with 4 dashes

Comment: Are you sure the ID is a guid?  It appears that it is an object with a guid property, and that guid is the default output of the object.

Comment: Have you tried `Get-Connections | % {Remove-Connection "$($_.Id)"}`?

Comment: Can you post the code for both of your functions please?

Comment: Yes mjolinor, the ID is a guid. @ BobLobLaw the code doesnt work either. @ Ranney: I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I have to set the Get-Connections command in brackets:

```
(Get-Connections) | % { Remove-Connection $_.Id }
```